# ng-if showing empty DOM element when condition is not true

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if, angularjs-ng-if

I have the following in a view file:

```
  <p class="presentation black">Sections:
    <span data-ng-if="currentTab == 'tab1'">
      <div ng-repeat="question in filtered = (template.questions | unique:'sectionName')"></div>
      <p class="presentation black">{{filtered.length}}</p>
    </span>
    <span data-ng-if="currentTab == 'tab2'">
      <div ng-repeat="sheet in filtered = (template.sections[0].sheets | unique:'name')"></div>
      <p class="presentation black">{{filtered.length}}</p>
    </span>
  </p>
```

When `tab1` is selected, the information is displayed correctly.  However when on `tab2`,  it appears that `<p>` element in both spans is being displayed - an empty value in displayed for the `<p>` element related to `tab1`.  By looking at the DOM tree it also seems that when on `tab2`, the `ng-if` condition is not displaying: `<!-- end ngIf: currentTab == 'tab2' -->`.  Can anyone see where the issue may be?  Let me know if more code is required.

Comment: Post a complete example reproducing the problem, as a plunkr. Look at your console for an error.

Comment: <p> shouldn't be in a <span>  according to HTML5 specs.  Change the <span> to a <div> and see what happens.

Comment: @jbrown excellent - that has fixed the problem

Comment: @KvnH please mark answered if resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "p" shouldn't be in a "span" according to HTML5 specs. Change the "span" to a "div".

HTML

```
<p class="presentation black">Sections:
   <div data-ng-if="currentTab == 'tab1'">
     <div ng-repeat="question in filtered = (template.questions | unique:'sectionName')"></div>
     <p class="presentation black">{{filtered.length}}</p>
   </div>
   <div data-ng-if="currentTab == 'tab2'">
     <div ng-repeat="sheet in filtered = (template.sections[0].sheets | unique:'name')"></div>
     <p class="presentation black">{{filtered.length}}</p>
   </div>
</p>
```